# Set OSX status bar app image colour

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I have a frustrating problem. Ive created a StatusBar (MenuBar) app and attached a logo to it. Problem is no matter what colour the image I use for my logo is, it always turns out grey scaled in the statusBar. Drop box has a blue and green icon so I know its possible just don't know how. The image im using is a PNG btw

Comment: Not sure, but I know Anti-Social actually toggles between a grey and a colored icon on the Status Bar, depending on whether the app's timer is running or not.  Because of that, it's probably not a setting for the app as a whole or the icon file itself, it's probably a property in the AppDelegate or something similar, which can be changed during the app's execution.  I don't have much OS X experience, though, so that's all the help I can offer.

Comment: Appreciate it, hope fully someone knows exactly what that property is

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this out. Incase anyone stumbles upon this and needs an answer. What had happened was, I had set `setTemplate` to YES on my highlight image. I had seen this in a tutorial I followed to learn how to make a statusMenu app in the first place. Removing this line fixed everything